# how to update associated models using Sequelize in one call

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, hapi.js

I am able to insert associated model all in one using build and include but not able to update in a one call :(

sample data which I want to update

{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Cleansheet Type8",
    "description": "Description for Cleansheet Type1",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "TenantId": null,
    "Sections": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "section8",
        "CleansheetTypeId": 19,
        "Variables": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "variable8",
            "type": "string",
            "defaultFlag": true,
            "defaultVal": "someVal",
            "requiredFlag": true,
            "comment": "some comment",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

Answer (score 0):

In `Sequelize` its not possible to update related models. You have to break your query into two steps and use combination of [create](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#createvalues-options-promiseinstance) and [bulkCreate](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#bulkcreaterecords-options-promisearrayinstance). it would look something like this -

```
User.findOrCreate(req.body.user).then(function(user){
  return Follow.bulkCreate([record1, record2, record3]);
});
```

Comment: insert is possible using build and save like this : Model.CleansheetType.build(req.payload, {

            include: [{model: Model.Section,  include: [{model:Model.Variable}]}]
        })
        .save()
        .then((result)=>{
            reply(result);
        })

Comment: hmm, wasn't aware about insert, but update might not be available